# Get records between two columns using range between two dates, Also search filter criteria

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

**I want to get records that are joined between this date period (2022-02-15, 2022-08-20)**

```
$users = User::whereDate('start_at', '>=', $startDate)
            ->whereDate('end_at', '<=', $endDate)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_start_date = '2022-02-15';
$_end_date ='2022-08-20';

$users = User::where(function ($query) use ($_start_date, $_end_date) {
                    $query->where(function ($query) use ($_start_date, $_end_date) {
                        $query->whereRaw("start_date >= date('$_start_date')")
                            ->whereRaw("end_date <= date('$_end_date')");
                    })
                    ->orwhere(function ($query) use ($_start_date, $_end_date) {
                        $query->whereRaw("start_date <= date('$_start_date')")
                            ->whereRaw("end_date >= date('$_end_date')");
                    });
                })->get();
```

**try above code** this will also return between dates of start_date and end _date e.g below

```
$_start_date = '2022-02-18';
$_end_date ='2022-08-20';
```

and also works with below dates e.g

```
$_start_date = '2022-02-16';
$_end_date ='2022-08-18';
```

codes look like this in ide
[image]

Comment: this is also relevant and working in Lumen and Laravel frameworks, eloquent search queries

Comment: Thank U, It working fine as expected when getting range between dates

Answer (score 1):

You can use the whereBetween Laravel function:

```php
$users = User::whereBetween('start_at', [ $startDate, $endDate])->get();
```

**Note** $startDate and $endDate must be instance of Carbon.

```
$startDate = new Carbon('paste_your_start_date')->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00";
```

#### Update

This would be one method to get data from two seperated columns. Example is not tested.

```php
$start_at = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '2022-02-15 0')->toDateString();
$end_at = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '2022-08-20 0')->toDateString();

$users = User::whereRaw("start_at <=  date('$start_at')")
                      ->whereRaw("end_at >=  date('$end_at')")
                      ->get();
```

Comment: Thank for you your answer but This start_at will be search between $startDate & $endDate, But I want to search start_date & end_date (2022-02-15, 2022-08-20).

Comment: @AnilPahelajani Ok. i see. I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you need exactly

```
User::whereDate('start_date', '>=', $startDate)->where('end_date', '<=', $endDate)->get();
```

or

```
User::whereDate('start_date', '<', $User)->whereDate('end_date', '>', $startDate)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the records that at least one day from `start_date` to `end_date` that exists between 2022-02-15 and 2022-08-20:

```
$startDate = '2022-02-15';
$endDate = '2022-08-20';
$users = User::whereDate('start_at', '<=', $endDate) // where or whereDate also should work
    ->whereDate('end_at', '>=', $startDate)
    ->get();
```